Is there a mitzvah of Kavod or Oneg chol hamoed
In Halacha, is there a mitzvah of Kavod or Oneg chol hamoed like there is with Shabbat and Yom tov? Or no, even though they are special days is there not a specific requirement for Kavod or Oneg?

I’ve heard that on Sukkot one should try to have wine and meat every single of the 7 days, so clearly there’s some aspect of kavod or oneg

@CuriousYid - That's to do with simchat yom tov (which may be distinct from both kavod and oneg)

From Halachipedia regarding kavod Chol Hamoed:
Sh”t Rabbi Akiva Eiger 1 (in the Hashmatot) and S”A HaRav 529:5 write that there’s no Kavod and Oneg on Chol HaMoed. On the other hand, Magen Avraham 530:1, Mishna Brurah 530:1, Sefer Chol HaMoed (pg 1; by Rabbi Dovid Zucker) write that there’s Kavod and Oneg on Chol HaMoed, however, Shaar Tzion 530:4 points out that it’s not as strict as Kavod of Yom Tov. Yalkut Yosef (Moadim pg 502) agrees. Mechilta (Parshat Bo 9) derives from a pasuk that there is an obligation to honor Chol Hamoed with food, drinks, and nice clothing. Tanya Rabati (siman 52) writes that a person should eat and drink on Chol Hamoed like he does on Yom Tov. Shaar Hatziyun 530:4 concludes that the mechilta means that it is necessary to have food, drink, and clothing that is nicer than during the week but not necessarily like Yom Tov.
Mishna Brurah 530:1, Yalkut Yosef (Moadim pg 502), and Aruch HaShulchan 530:4 write that there’s an obligation to wear clothing which is a little nicer than regular weekday clothing. Shaar Hatziyun 530:4 clarifies that it isn't necessary to wear Shabbat or Yom Tov clothing. It is sufficient to wear clothing that are a little nicer than during the week. Peninei Halacha (Moadim 10:3) agrees that chol hamoed clothing just need to be slightly nicer than weekday clothing. Nimukei Orach Chaim 530:3 and Chaye Adam 106:1 hold that one should wear Shabbat clothes, but one doesn’t need to wear Yom Tov clothing which are supposed to be a little better than Shabbat clothing. Mishna Brurah 530:1 writes that the Maharil's practice was to wear Shabbat clothes on Chol HaMoed.
Shulchan Aruch O.C. 188:7 writes that since there’s no obligation to have a meal on Chol HaMoed is one forgets Yaaleh VeYavo one doesn’t repeat Brikat HaMazon. Magen Avraham 530:1, Mishna Brurah 530:1, and Yalkut Yosef (Moedim pg 502) write that it’s preferable to have bread since Kavod is with food and the most important food is bread. Regarding having nice meals on Chol HaMoed, see Rashi's comment to Avot 3:11.
